# How to make bootable flash drive on kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, flash, iso

So what program or command should I use to create bootable flash drive?
I used UnetBootin, disk creator and I think they are not working as they should . When I use option for boot with flash drive says "Boot Error" or nothing happen.

I'm running Kubuntu 15.10 , 64 bit system.

-I have 4gb memory on the stick.

-fat32

Comment: Which OS do you want to burn?

Comment: I want to burn Kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try Rufus. The URL address is https://rufus.akeo.ie/
It's very easy to use, almost self explanatory.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Rufus is a Windows app.

Comment: Then master_28 might use YUMI. The URL address is http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/